# Web API 400 exception turning into 500 Exception in another environment

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have same version of application deployed to my dev as well as qa environment.

Based on some business scenario, I generate bad business exception which is 400 type. In dev it works fine but in QA it does not work for me.

The exception is turning into 500 error.The code below show is used.
in Dev the response.Data has the info but in QA it is undefined.

```
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: urlString,
  data: $.param(data),
}).then(function(response) {
    debugger;
    if (response.status == 200) {
      return response.data;
    } else {
      // invalid response
      return $q.reject(response.data);
    }
  },
  function(response) { // optional
    // failed
    return $q.reject(response.data);
  });
```

Any idea how to root cause it?

Comment: `response` usually has information on the error. See in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, under `general usage`

Comment: Any chance this could actually be a 500 exception in QA?

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti - No it is not. But anyways, We needed to reinstall the IIS to resolve it. The only issue I could attribute is that when the server was given to us (which was causing issue) was cloned from another server. So we gave a shot at reinstalling IIS afresh. It worked.